# Smooth Qt Window Switching on Symbian^3 phone

Tags: qt, window, symbian, switching

It is flicking when switching window/form. How to make it smooth? for instance,sliding in and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out QPropertyAnimation. This allows you to slide your Widgets in.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a direct answer .but I've observed that complicated and incorrect use of Qlayout results on flickering when displaying QWidgets/QFrames etc.